# What can the Petrified Something be used for?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Since I'm a sucker for mystery gifts in Dark Souls, I chose the "Petrified Something" as my starting gift. Knowing what I knew about the Old Witch's Ring in Dark Souls, I figured that the item's usefulness (if it had any at all) wouldn't become apparent until much later in the game.

Imagine my surprise, then, when I came across the birds' nest *in the tutorial area* that enticingly asked me for a "smooth" object. Figuring that my petrified lump fit the bill quite well, I dropped it in the nest, and got a White Ring in exchange.

That's a neat ring, of course, but since I traded away my starting gift only minutes into the game, it makes me curious if I've now missed out on anything else I could've used it for instead. Does the Petrified Something have any other uses than to trade at the birds' nest?

Comment: The trade list is randomized. Some examples: http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/petrified-something. I got a titanite slab when I traded it.

Comment: Good find! I also thought I'd throw in here that I found a second Petrified Something in a chest, so it's not even a truly unique item.

Comment: Shouldn't this post be marked as spoiler?

Comment: I think I managed to get an old favourite weapon from dark souls 1: the stray demons hammer when I traded it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The one and the only use for the Petrified Something is in the tutorial's nest. As mentioned before, [the item you will receive in return is randomized](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/petrified-something). No other relevant uses for the PS are known as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

i used it and got a titanite that is able to upgrade a weapon once after normally reachign max upgrade lvl.

Answer (score -3):

You use it at Brightstone Cove, after defeating the boss. You touch that little colorful pool, then leave and come back, and revive the dragon.

Comment: pretty sure you are referring to the ashen mist heart, not petrified something.

Answer (score -6):

You can use it to heal petrification on a mob